# Query/Filter CSV/Excel with multiple values in different row corresponding to a single row

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, vba

I have a CSV file which I am opening in Excel. I need to filter/query my data. 
Sample data is -

```
|S.no|Name|Value|
| 1  | A  | 52  |
|    |    | 63  |
|    |    | 65  |
|    |    | 22  |
| 2  | B  | 32  |
|    |    | 65  |
| 3  | C  | 82  |
|    |    | 22  |
```

If I want to query/filter from "Value" for "65", I want the result to show "A" and "B".

```
|1| A| 65|
|2| B| 65|
```

Similarly if I query for "22" I want the result as "A" and "C".

```
|1| A| 22|
|3| C| 22|
```

I tried the approach explained here - https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3382-excel-filter-comma-separated.html
But is doesn't return the "Name" when filtered using this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter for each column, and fill down the blanks in `[S.no]` and `[Name]`. Then you can use a pivot table for users:

[image]

Comment: I figured, however rewriting the "name"/"sno" column in every row would reduce the appeal of the file for the users. I am preferably looking for an alternate way.

Comment: thanks, this seems to help. I am not sure how to use pivot table, can you elaborate a bit more.  Thanks

Comment: For sure! check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if extra-columns are allowed, can you please try this also...
Formulas in E3, F3 can be copied down.
[image]

You can do a copy paste-values in your original cells.

Hope this helps